# If $f(1/z)$ has a pole at z=0 then $f(z)$ is polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis

The condition is that $f$ is entire and injective, but the fact that it is injective might be an overkill. How can I prove this statement? I am having trouble understanding what the sufficient condition for the polynomial is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I moved my comment here since it was closer to an answer than a comment:

Since f is entire it has a Taylor series at the origin which converges everywhere:

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n, |z|<\infty$$

Plug in 1/z into this expression. This will become a Laurent series, which you know properties about since you know $z=0$ is a pole of $f(\frac{1}{z})$. In particular, you know that the Laurent series has finitely many terms.

Comment: Thank you. How do we know that the order of pole at $z=0$ is finite?

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. That was a dumb question. Thanks so much.

Comment: If the principal part of a Laurent series around $z$ has infinitely many terms, then $z$ is an essential singularity of $f$ and not a pole.